# sorting data using button in php

Tags: php, html, sorting, button

I tried to create a button which the function is to sort data either descending or ascending. However, I don't have idea how to do it

I did some research in internet, but none of them give the answer.

anyone know how to do it or some source code which can be a references???

this is my code
test.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Data Mining</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="showDB.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Foreign Agent Country</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
      </tr>
        <td>
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value-"Submit">
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

showDB.php

```
<?php
//connect to server
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

//connect to database
//select the database
mysql_select_db("fak_databases");

//submit button
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $country = $_POST['country'];
}

//query the database
if($country == 'US') {  
    // query to get all US records  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='US'");  
}  
elseif($country == 'NZ') {  
    // query to get all AUD records  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='NZ'"); 
}elseif($country == 'JP') {  
    // query to get all AUD records  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='JP'");  
} else {  
    // query to get all records  
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample"); 
}  
//fetch the result
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
//ascending descending button
Print "<tr><th colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='asc_sort' value-'Asc'></input></th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
    Print "<td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
}
    //sorting the data, I got from internet but doesn't work
    if(isset($_POST['asc_sort']) && !empty($_POST['asc_sort']) && $_POST['asc_sort']==1)
    {
         $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample ORDER BY invention_title ASC";

    }else{

        $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample ORDER BY invention_title DESC";
    }

Print "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Print "<tr><th colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='asc_sort' value-'Asc'></input></th></tr>";
```

To

```
Print "<tr><th colspan='2'><input type='submit' name='asc_sort' value='Asc'></input></th></tr>";
```

And this

```
if(isset($_POST['asc_sort']) && !empty($_POST['asc_sort']) && $_POST['asc_sort']==1)
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['asc_sort']) && !empty($_POST['asc_sort']))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Data Mining</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="showDB.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Foreign Agent Country</td>
        <td>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="asc" value="1" /> Ascending?</td>
      </tr>
     <tr> 
        <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value-"Submit">
        </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Few things:

- You were pulling a query statement in the middle of a while where
  you're still retrieving the previous statement. This would require
  pulling the data into multiple arrays and then processing.
- You should be using something like pdo or mysqli for this, but here's an
  example with your current methods.
- Also you were using isset on POST... if POST has anything in it, it will return as set.
- Referencing a POST variable that is not set will cause an error, So I'm checking to make sure that country is set then I'm provided a NULL answer to the switch.

Example Code:

```
<?php
    //connect to server
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    //connect to database
    //select the database
    mysql_select_db("fak_databases");

    //submit button
    if(!empty($_POST['formSubmit'])&&($_POST['formSubmit']=="Submit")&&(!empty($_POST['country']))){
        $country = $_POST['country'];
    } else {
        $country = '';  
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['asc']))
        {
             $append = " ORDER BY invention_title ASC";

        }else{

            $append = " ORDER BY invention_title DESC";
        }

    switch($country){
    case 'US':
    $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='US'$append";
    break;
    case 'NZ':
    $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='NZ'$append";
    break;
    case 'JP':
    $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='JP'$append";
    break;
    default:
    //all records
    $query = "SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample$append";

    }

    //query the database
    if($result = mysql_query($query)){
    //fetch the result
    print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

        print "<tr>";
        print "<td>".$row['invention_title'] . "</td>"; 
        print "<td>".$row['invention-title'] . " </td></tr>"; 
    }
        //sorting the data, I got from internet but doesn't work


    print "</table>";
    } else {
                    //For Testing
        echo "Query Failed:<br />$query";   
    }


?>
```

Comment: thanks man..it's working..but in my case, I want to add button in my next page and the button will do the ascending and descending...is it possible to do in php???or should I use javascript because I did some research that said javascript...

Comment: You can sort with either really. Most people will create a button that is Javascript that will call a PHP  and return the updated sort via Ajax to replace whatever is there.

Comment: I would need to see and example of the output and the tables being used to provide another example.